# How easy is it to kill a Mudhorn?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In S1E2 of *The Mandalorian*, the protagonist encountered a creature that he later referred to as a "mudhorn".

In the battle, the creature was exceedingly strong, overpowering the Mandalorian. His rifle malfunctioned and it looked like the creature would kill him, but in the end (and with help) the mudhorn died very easily.

> After the mudhorn charged the Mandlaorian and threw him through air for the third time, we see him dazed, bruised, holding out a small dagger as the large creature charges toward him one final time. The "yoda species" baby uses a force-like power to lift the mudhorn in the air, saving the Mandalorian. The Mandalorian stabs the mudhorn (with the small dagger) and it dies.

How could this have happened? The dagger only seems to be a few inches long.

A small wound from a dagger would be unlikely to kill such a large creature.

Was he just lucky?

Was the dagger poisoned?

Did the Mandalorian know about and target a "weak spot" on the mudhorn?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you see in *The Mandalorian* S1E3, they are using vibro blades, from the Wookieepedia [article on Vibroblade](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Vibroblade):

> The vibroblade was used either as an offensive weapon that could be hammered into an opponent's defenses, or as a utility device. The weapon buzzed, thrummed, and glowed ember-hot when ignited and, when tasked to cut, could be used as a crude surgical implement capable of cutting into an animal's innards. They were also capable of **punching through the plastoid armor of a stormtrooper**. Such weapons were often kept in sheaths or scabbards.

[image: Vibroblade in The Mandalorian]

That scene is around Minute 10, Second 30, I unfortunately do not have the tools to create a gif or short video out of it and was not able to find it online. You really see the blade is moving. As it's able to cut through Stormtrooper armour, it wont be a problem cutting through skin, even if it is thick skin. Then, you only need to know where to hit. You see that the mudhorn was hit in the neck, a very sensitive part of the body in all known creatures. The mudhorn bled out very fast (while butchering, it may take minutes to bleed to death) but it is not  unlikely that the knife cut through the mudhorns skin easily.

Edit: found videos of the vibroblade. If you watch the video when the mudhorn attacks the Mandalorian, the blade is vibrating.

Also here, you see it more clearly and longer that the blade is vibrating:

Comment: Vibrodblades? *Vibro*blades?! Sweet, aching Gamma World!

Comment: @Lexible Glad to see I'm not the only Gamma World fan around.

Comment: @mwarren You are among friends here. :)